# Saving MapServer output to file?

Tags: mapserver, image

How can I save the results from a MapServer file as an image? I would like to be able to write a png file as a result of a query. My query which I can display in browser is the following:

```
http://mysite.com/mapserv.cgi?map=../../mapfiles/demo.map&layer=land&mode=map&FORMAT=image/png
```

I have tried the following (which does not seem to work):

```
wget http://mysite.com/mapserv.cgi?map=../../mapfiles/demo.map&layer=land&mode=map&FORMAT=image/png
```

and also

```
wget http://mysite.com/mapserv.cgi?map=../../mapfiles/demo.map&layer=land&mode=map&FORMAT=image/png >> myfile.png
```

I have seen the [shp2img](http://mapserver.org/utilities/shp2img.html) function but that appears to be used just for testing mapfiles. In this case I would like to use a SQL filter with my mapfile, which I don't think I can do using shp2img.

---

Included first `wget` attempt that I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also asked this question on the MapServer mailing list, and Jukka Rahkonen suggested the following approach which fixed my problem:

> Perhaps wget thinks that certain characters are cutting the URL
>   string. Try wget
>   "http://mysite.com/mapserv.cgi?map=../../mapfiles/demo.map&layer=land&mode=map&FORMAT=image/png"
>   -O output.png
>
> We have used wget a lot for downloading data from WCS so I guarantee
>   you will make it work by reading documents and trying just like we
>   did.

Comment: The problem is that the shell interprets the & as the fork to background command, so wget sends only part of the url to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
wget http://mysite.com/mapserv.cgi?map=../../mapfiles/demo.map&layer=land&mode=map&FORMAT=image/png
```

You are getting some wget log output in your image file. See the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) for other information about how wget works.

Comment: That does not work for me. I get a file of this type `mapserv.cgi?map=..%2F..%2Fmapfiles%2Fdemo.map`. If I try renaming it to `test.png` it is not an image (I should have included this in my question as I had also tried it).

Comment: I just tried it using GeoServer and it works for me.

Comment: what is in the file?

Comment: It turns out to be an error message `mapserv(): Web application error. Traditional BROWSE mode requires a TEMPLATE in the WEB section, but none was provided.` However, I can view it in my browser when I paste the same command in.

Comment: so there's something wrong with your mapserver set up

Comment: add &mode=map to your URL string